# How to use Google DLP API to delete sensitive content from data stored in Google Big Query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pii, google-cloud-dlp

I have a certain table in Google Big Query which has some sensitive fields. I read and understood about [inspection](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/inspecting-storage) of data but cannot find a way to redact the data using DLP API directly in BigQuery database.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to do it just using DLP API?
2. If not, what is the best way to fix data in a table which runs into Terabytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API does not yet support de-identifying bigquery directly.

You can however write a dataflow pipeline that leverages content.deidentify. If you batch your rows utilizing Table objects (https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/ContentItem#Table) this can work pretty efficiently.

Comment: Does it support de-identifying BQ table directly? I do not see any update on this